# Error:(22, 25) Integer types not allowed (at 'black' with value '000000'). in values.xml file in Android

Tags: android, xml, colors

I created a color from the layout using Alt + Enter , i entered the wrong value for the color witch is 000000 , i fogot to put "#" , so i have this problem of 
Error:(22, 25) Integer types not allowed (at 'black' with value '000000').
And i can't find the color i defined in the color.xml file.
I have tried to find a solutin online , i didn't find any answer , i hope the someone of you could help me guys , Have a great day and thank you in advance
.........(i am adding this text just for stack overflow to accpet my question)

Comment: Edit > Find > Find in path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error(22,25) points to the location of the error, it is not the name of the error.

Check in your layout_main.xml file to make sure that everything is defined correctly.

Check your Mainactivity.java file to make sure there are no syntax errors.

Please respond if this does not resolve the issue.